# EF Core FromSQLRaw and Stored Procedures to insert data

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a Entity Framework Core application. I have a stored procedure which I use to insert data. The stored procedure is used elsewhere so I cannot change it.

When I call it to create an entry, it does not work because the `Description` column is not returned from the stored procedure. So I get an error when I call `FromSQLRaw` unless I set `Description` as `[NotMapped]`.

However, I don't want to use `[NotMapped]` because I might do something like

```
dm.Offices.Where(o => o.Id > 10)
```

and surely `[NotMapped]` will not return unmapped columns. So what can I do?

```
using (var dm = new DatabaseModel())
{
    Office london = new Office { Description = "london" };
    var item = dm.Offices.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE sp_addoffice {0}", london.Description);
}
```

```
public partial class Office
{
    [Key, Column("OfficeID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public partial class DatabaseModel : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Office> Offices { get; set; }
}
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Offices]
(
    [OfficeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NULL
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_addoffice]
    @Description varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO offices (Description) 
    VALUES (@Description)

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS OfficeID
END
```

Comment: One solution appears to be, using GetDBConnection, I can use non-EF calls e.g. ExecuteNonQuery to call the stored proc that way, but I would rather have a solution using the EF calls.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Create new class

```
public class OfficeId
{
public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

Add this class to you EF context:

```
public virtual DbSet<OfficeId> OfficeIds { get; set; }

   modelBuilder.Entity<OfficeId>(e =>
            {
                e.HasNoKey();
            });
```

After this use just this:

```
 var officeId = dm.OfficeIds.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE sp_addoffice {0}", london.Description);
```

After this you can use this you can validate an officeId.Id and use any way you  are needed.

Comment: Thanks. This is great to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the SQL to something that returns the proper shape after running the stored procedure.  EG:

```
set nocount on;
declare @ids table(id int);

insert into @ids(id)
execute sp_addoffice {0};

select *
from offices 
where id = ( select top 1 id from @ids );
```